# Windows: is there a common hot key to favorite an item?

Tags: windows-os, keyboard-shortcuts

As per title: I have a list with "favorite" markers for its items, I want to add a keyboard shortcut to toggle the favorite status of an item.

is there any typical keyboard assignment in commonly used, popular applications for that?

Comment: Do you mean you are designing an application with items that you can favourite?

Answer (score 2):

The shortcut to add a favorite in browsers is command+d (mac) or ctrl+d (windows). For applications in general, I suggest you have a look at https://defkey.com/. If you search for "ctrl+d" (https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-d), for example, it shows a variety of different meanings for different applications.

Comment: Great resource! I guess the type of application and the intended users would dictate which shortcut to go with.

Comment: Defkey's search gives you [a list of shortcuts used for adding favourites](https://defkey.com/search?irq=add+to+favorites)

Answer (score 1):

It would depend on the language you have already used. Im not sure if you have access to see Atalassin but their keyboard shortcuts appear almost random yet product managers seem to effortlessly remember them all.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/agile066/jira-agile-user-s-guide/using-keyboard-shortcuts

Dribbble uses 'l' because they use 'like' as the Call to action.

In summary so long as they are sensible i.e. Favorite 'f' and you are clear that this feature exists, then there shouldn't be any confusion.

Comment: This is valuable advice but keep in mind that the OP wants to know if a commonly used shortcut exists.